# Performing Matrix.mapPoints() in both directions

Tags: android, matrix

In a word game I use a [Matrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html) to define scrolling offset and scaling of an image representing the game board:

[image: app screenshot]

When I play letter tiles to the game board, I convert from screen coordinates (the finger touch coordinates in `onTouchEvent`) to the game board coordinates (to know where to put the tile) by the following method:

```
public PointF screenToBoard(PointF screenPoint) {
    float[] point = new float[] {screenPoint.x, screenPoint.y};
    Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
    mMatrix.invert(inverse);
    inverse.mapPoints(point);
    float boardX = point[0];
    float boardY = point[1];
    return new PointF(boardX, boardY);
}
```

**My question is:** how to do the opposite conversion?

I.e. when I move the letter tiles from the game board to the blue bar at the bottom of the screen (for example when cancelling my turn) - how can I please convert back from game board coordinates to the screen coordinates?

The Android doc on the `mapPoints` method is *very* scarce.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found the solution:

```
public PointF boardToScreen(PointF boardPoint) {
    float[] point = new float[] {boardPoint.x, boardPoint.y};
    mMatrix.mapPoints(point);
    float screenX = point[0];
    float screenY = point[1];
    return new PointF(screenX, screenY);
}
```